# Function to create a valid id from string. Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Im creating an ID from elements `name` attribute and they have some not allowed characters, I would like to create a function that replaces charcters if they are not on the list with `_`.  I tried to google it, but all I found was regexp examples with where not quite what Im looking for.

This is what I made:

```
/([^A-Za-z0-9[\]{}_-])\s?/g
```

but this doesn't exclude `]` and `[`, maybe some other characters too.

How can I make that it replaces all characters with `_` that are not `[A-Za-z0-9]`, `-`, `_`, `.`, `:`?

**EDITED**

.. and if first character is not a number make it one.

If somebody knows a better way how to do it, please share it.

Comment: You have already implemented a regular expression that excludes everything but the set of given characters.

Comment: But it does not exclude '[' , ']' You can check it here: http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 35):

Have you tried just the Not word character (i.e. `\W`) matches everything that is not A-Za-z0-9_ (which also means a space)

so

```
/\W/g
```

in javascript something like

```
var id = "What ever your id is [] {} - &";
var cleanedId = id.replace(/\W/g,'_'); //cleanedId is "What_ever_your_id_is__________"
```

Assuming your replacing them all with an underscore of course

Example regex [here](http://www.regexr.com/39ata)

Comment: would this work if the string had special characters in it?

Comment: @RafikBari the Regex matches everything that is NOT A-Za-z0-9 and _, so if you consider a 'special character' to NOT be one of these , then yes it would match special characters, as per my example of matching [], {}, - and &. Although you really need to clarify what 'special characters' you are referring to

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you @OJay

Comment: This doesn't handle the situation where the text leads with a number BTW.

Comment: Inspired by the comment from @TomasZubrik below, you could pre-empt handling leading numbers by prefixing the string with `id_` rather than adding it conditionally. For example, using a template literal `id_${'007 James Bond'.replace(/\W/g, '_').toLowerCase()}` would result in 'id_007_james_bond'.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the replace() function as following:

```
var temp = "some id to validate";
var i = "";
if(!$.isNumeric(temp[0])){
    i = parseInt(Math.random()*10);
}
temp = i+temp.replace(/([^A-Za-z0-9[\]{}_.:-])\s?/g, '');
//here the id is a valid id
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zLLk9hs/2/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this with exceptions handling:**

```
function createValidHtmlId(value) {
  const id = value ? value.replace(/\W/g, '_') : '_';
  return id.charAt(0).match(/[\d_]/g)?.length ? `id_${id}` : id;
}
```

**How it works:**

- `result = value_without_non_word_chars_underscore_separated;`
- If value is `null`, `undefined` or empty string `''` --> `'id__'` is returned
- If value starts with special non-word character `\W` --> `'id__'` or `'id_${result}'` is returned
- If value starts with number --> `'id_${result}'` is returned
- Otherwise --> `result` is returned

**Hope it helps!**